# Derive a rotation matrix to partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, rotations

I have the following rotation matrix:

> [u  =  [cos θ  -sin θ|  [x
>    v]  =  |sin θ   cos θ]    y]

the rotation matrix is 2x2 (I apologize for my bad html skills)

And I need to show that the following is true:

d^2f/dx^2 + d^2f/dy^2 =  d^2f/du^2 + d^2f/dv^2 (d=delta, so it's second derivative)

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated,

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Apply the chain rule a few times.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!